# Power Query cell has fewer characters in it than the source cell

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm using Power Query to pull data from a folder with between 2 and 40 excel files. One of the cells I'm pulling includes an explanation, sometimes a lengthy explanation, but Power Query is only displaying 2-3 sentences and not the entire thread.

When I am setting Power Query up, the preview is showing a truncated version of the source explanation. Accordingly, the final PQ output is truncated. However, I would like PQ to display the entire explanation.

Source explanation:
"Joe went out to Orica (On the last day of the month) to bill out safety that they were in need of.  Jamie Kennedy (GAM) is working on getting their safety fill list put together.  Some of the pricing was not entered correctly/some of the items were not allowed to be billed from the PRC (but they were allowed on their fill list).  Joe only needed $460 to hit his safety goal - and with these items he would have exceeded the goal.  The price update would not go through until Friday, so we were unable to backdate the invoices.  Email exchange between myself, and Jamie are attached.  I also attached a copy of the handwritten, this is the sorbent pads that are 55.75each - the SSR dropped off 12. ($669)"

Power Query output:
"Joe went out to Orica (On the last day of the month) to bill out safety that they were in need of.  Jamie Kennedy (GAM) is working on getting their safety fill list put together.  Some of the pricing was not entered correctly/some of the items were not al"

I want the Power Query output to match the Source Explanation.

Comment: [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a8bc142-019a-4e6e-b853-c3d4bfff1aea/text-truncated-to-255-characters-when-importing-from-xsls-but-not-from-csv?forum=powerquery) may be useful, not sure.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the suggested article. Unfortunately, my source documents have headers longer than 255 characters and it still truncates the cell.

Also, according to this article, Power Query doesn't have a known character limit.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-specifications-and-limits-5fb2807c-1b16-4257-aa5b-6793f051a9f4

So... I'm confused.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I'm just as confused. What is the file format/extension, by chance?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Your sentence has 700 characters and it is **NOT** being truncated when imported and then exported to/from Power Query.

Comment: @BigBen, I'm using .xls and/or .xlsx depending on who is submitting.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, are you putting the data into excel and importing that or data scraping from this page?

Comment: Have you checked if this only happens in .xls files? I've seen some weird issues with the .xls importer before, wouldn't be surprised if this is another one.

Comment: What is the cell address of the example you mentioned being truncated. It may have something to do with the character limit for a header of a table.

Comment: @R.Dawg I copy/pasted it from your quote into an Excel cell.  I then did a `Get Data from Table/Range` to move it into `PQ`.  It does seem to be the case that a column header has a 255 character limit, but not a cell in the column.